# Macros -> ->> in Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

Are the `->` and `->>` macros only to make the code more readable or they have also other specific functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thread-first (`->`) and thread-last (`->>`) are there to make code more readable. But that's already pretty important !

It allows to un-nest function calls (example taken from [clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E)) :

```
;; Arguably a bit cumbersome to read:
user=> (first (.split (.replace (.toUpperCase "a b c d") "A" "X") " "))
"X"

;; Perhaps easier to read:
user=> (-> "a b c d" 
           .toUpperCase 
           (.replace "A" "X") 
           (.split " ") 
           first)
```

It also allows you to put the emphasis on something. For instance, consider  :

```
(-> {... }
    ...
    ...
    (count)) 

(count (...(... {...})))
```

In the first example, it is very clear that you start with a map, and then do something to it. In the second, it is clear that you count something.

The preference depends on what you want to put forward.

Also, the choice of `->` vs `->>` is a clear visual indicator : are you operating or not on collections ? This is made immediately obvious (this is a convention in Clojure to have the collection as a last parameter).

So yes, it is "only" readability, but that is a very important part of building programs, and Clojure gives you tools to make your code read naturally. When choosing one solution, I try to consider [the way Clojure will be read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894209/how-to-read-mentally-lisp-clojure-code).

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's a family of related conditional threading macros which *do* add additional functionality on top of that. `some->` and `some->>` thread first and last as above, but halt evaluation if any step returns `nil`, a la the maybe monad. `cond->` and `cond->>` test a conditional to decide whether or not to pass the value through each of the threaded forms.

Comment: @nha Thank you, it is very clear now! By the way a new question came up to me reading your nice answer: do the points before the method names indicate java methods? (in `.replace` `.toUpperCase`) and is there any difference or benefit between calling the java methods vs. clojure libraries: `(clojure.string/replace)`  `(clojure.string/upper-case)` ?

Comment: @AmirTeymuri glad you like it :) Yes, those are Java methods (I just took the example from clojuredocs but yes the Clojure methods are more idiomatic). Also, when calling Java methods that are not in a Clojure namespace, you may be interested in the `doto` macro.

Comment: Why oh why name it 'threading' when it is really more like 'pipe'?